# Como gerar um dataframe com os resultados de uma regressão linear?

Tags: r

Usando a dataframe mtcars, estou estudando o calculo de regressões no R.

Para isso, fiz o seguinte script:

```
if(!require(pacman)) install.packages("pacman")
library(pacman)

pacman::p_load(dplyr, ggplot2, car, rstatix, lmtest, ggpmisc, data.table, writexl)


dataset <- mtcars

modtest <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt + vs, dataset)

summary.lm(modtest)
```

Agora, gostaria de passar os resultados da regressão para um dataframe,e assim baixar em csv ou xlsx, mas não encontro uma forma.

Como posso transformar o `summary.lm(modtest)` em uma dataframe ?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é usar a função `tidy()` do pacote {broom}:

```
broom::tidy(modtest)

# A tibble: 5 × 5
  term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (Intercept)  38.5       3.34     11.5    6.14e-12
2 cyl          -0.905     0.679    -1.33   1.94e- 1
3 hp           -0.0179    0.0122   -1.46   1.56e- 1
4 wt           -3.18      0.774    -4.11   3.26e- 4
5 vs            0.155     1.62      0.0957 9.24e- 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a função `coef`:

```r
dataset <- mtcars

modtest <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt + vs, dataset)

coef(summary(modtest))
#>                Estimate Std. Error     t value     Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) 38.48404581 3.33740414 11.53113145 6.143114e-12
#> cyl         -0.90501219 0.67894306 -1.33297213 1.936803e-01
#> hp          -0.01785427 0.01224378 -1.45823142 1.563120e-01
#> wt          -3.18355380 0.77368907 -4.11477159 3.264650e-04
#> vs           0.15457896 1.61535124  0.09569372 9.244706e-01
```

Entretanto, esse objeto não é um data frame:

```r
is.data.frame(coef(summary(modtest)))
#> [1] FALSE
```

Portanto, é necessário convertê-lo para um data frame:

```r
as.data.frame(coef(summary(modtest)))
#>                Estimate Std. Error     t value     Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) 38.48404581 3.33740414 11.53113145 6.143114e-12
#> cyl         -0.90501219 0.67894306 -1.33297213 1.936803e-01
#> hp          -0.01785427 0.01224378 -1.45823142 1.563120e-01
#> wt          -3.18355380 0.77368907 -4.11477159 3.264650e-04
#> vs           0.15457896 1.61535124  0.09569372 9.244706e-01
```

Mas se o objetivo for formatar essa tabela para um relatório ou apresentação, sugiro utilizar a função `knitr::kable`. Ela permite pegar esses resultados e transformá-los em uma tabela em markdown (como essa que colei a seguir), html ou LaTeX. O pacote `officer` ajuda a criar tabelas similares para o Word.

```r
library(knitr)
kable(coef(summary(modtest)))
```

|  | Estimate | Std. Error | t value | Pr(>|t|) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 38.4840458 | 3.3374041 | 11.5311314 | 0.0000000 |
| cyl | -0.9050122 | 0.6789431 | -1.3329721 | 0.1936803 |
| hp | -0.0178543 | 0.0122438 | -1.4582314 | 0.1563120 |
| wt | -3.1835538 | 0.7736891 | -4.1147716 | 0.0003265 |
| vs | 0.1545790 | 1.6153512 | 0.0956937 | 0.9244706 |

<sup>Created on 2023-05-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>